# Como ejecutar un post desde un text field en Razor Pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Amigos, en web form bastaba con asignar al TextBox un AutoPostBack="True", en Razor Pages...como realizo algo similar?
He probado con lo siguiente, pero no funciona:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.IdNroservicio" maxlength="9" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                   data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Enter para ejecutar" class="w-100" 
                   asp-page-handler="Prueba"/>



public IActionResult OnPostPrueba()
    {
        ViewData["PonerFoco"] = false;
        ViewData["chkActivo"] = false;
    ...
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, cuando presionas enter en un input text de un formulario, este hace submit automáticamente si hacer nada mas

Comment: Todos los ejemplos que he visto siempre utilizan un button para enviar, pero yo quiero hacerlo con un input text.
<button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Prueba"   -> Esto funciona
<input type="text"  asp-page-handler="Prueba" -> Esto no funciona

Comment: Estamos hablando cosas distintas. El AutoPostBack lo que hacía era gatillar submit al form cuando había un evento determinado (dependía del elemento). Tú tienes en tu input "Enter para ejecutar", por eso yo supuse que querías hacer el submit cuando presionara enter; y te respondo que cuando un input está dentro de un form, esto lo hace automáticamente sin tener que programar nada. Esto va a funcionar siempre y cuando el form tenga el action bien configurado (con la ruta del handler) o puedes colocar asp-page-handler="Prueba" directamente en el form, lo que tb debería funcionar

Comment: Amigo, las disculpas del caso, ya me di cuenta que si funciona, o al menos me funciona poniendo un form y dentro un solo imput, asi:        <form name="formsumi" method="post" asp-page-handler="Prueba">
    <input type="text" maxlength="9" title="Enter para ejecutar" />
</form>    si ya adiciono otro input, ahi ya no funcona. Pero ok, me sirve, gracias.